# Get ancestor with flag set

Tags: wagtail

Trying to add context menu of nested pages. To do so, added a boolean to the page model called "root_page".
How can I find the ancestor of the current page with this set to True? The calling page may be 1 to 3 levels down from the "root page".

Tried the following but it gives `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_ancestors'`

menu_tags.py:

```
def get_page_root(context, calling_page=None):
  ...
  root = calling_page.get_ancestors().live().filter(longscrollpage__root_page=True).first()
  ...
```

model.py:

```
class LongScrollPage(Page):
  ...
  include_left_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  root_page = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  ...
```

template.html:

```
...
{% if page.include_left_menu == True %}
  {% get_page_root calling_page=self %}
...
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "Trying to add context menu of nested pages. "

Comment: Can you show the model definition where you're defining the `root_page` boolean, please? The situation will be different depending on whether that's happening on one specific page model, an abstract base class used on multiple pages, or a non-abstract base class.

Comment: FWIW, the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_ancestors'` would imply that you're passing `None` as `calling_page`, and clearly the query can't work at all in that situation - so that's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Try `{% get_page_root calling_page=page %}`

Comment: Using `calling_page=page` gives the same `NoneType`. I have a different tag that is called the same way and it recognizes the calling_page no problem.